# How to create an average line in stacked column chart?

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I fetch data from server as two columns, date as xAxis, and decimal number as yAxis. I need to create HTML5 chart in iReport/Jasper studio (for example stacked column chart type) using those columns (easy part) and then I need to create one line on yAxis that will represent average value of second (decimal) column for whole dataset.

Something like this

[image: Expected outcome]

I tried to create two variables "sum" and "count" with reset type "report" and create measure as division of those two values to get average data set for whole report. Chart is not considering that value as constant while rendering yAxis points. For example, if I have 25 rows in dataset, for each point on graph it will decrease value of "sum" variable for 1....so "sum" will have values, 25, 24, 23,....,1 while line is rendered on chart.

Tried with StackedColumnLine chart type, but same results.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Hi, it is highchart behind

Comment: Probably I missed tag, I wanted to add highchart

Comment: Hmm no its not your fault they have introduce this by editing, I will retract vote and correct your post...

Comment: If you submit an [mcve] I can try it tonight, have no energy creating my own report to try.

Comment: I will try to do that till night, thx. Data is confident, so I cannot directly post that example.

Comment: For chart itself - if you set [`plotLine`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines) that have set value, then at that value line will be plotted. Plot lines can be added dynamically if you need to wait for data to be calculated - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine If you need to change value of plotLine, then instead of update you should remove the old and add a new plotLine.